# PHP Scope Resolution Operator Question

Tags: php, kohana, scope

I'm having trouble with the `MyClass::function();` style of calling methods and can't figure out why. Here's an example (I'm using Kohana framework btw):

```
    class Test_Core
 {
  public $var1 = "lots of testing";

  public function output()
   {
    $print_out = $this->var1;
    echo $print_out;
   }
 }
```

I try to use the following to call it, but it returns $var1 as undefined:

```
Test::output()
```

However, this works fine:

```
  $test = new Test(); 
  $test->output();
```

I generally use this style of calling objects as opposed to the "new Class" style, but I can't figure out why it doesn't want to work.

Comment: I don't know why but most of the script didn't show up in the code section. It looked fine when I previewed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this :

```
Test::output()
```

You are calling your method as a static one -- and static methods don't have access to instance properties, as there is no instance.

If you want to use a property, you must instanciate the class, to get an object -- and call the methods on that object.

A couple of links to the manual, as a reference :

- The **[Classes and Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)** section *-- you should really read this section ;-)*
- [Properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)
- [The Basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)
- **[Static Keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)** -- *Interesting too, for this specific question ;-)*

Quoting the last page I linked to :

> Because static methods are callable
> without an instance of the object
> created, the pseudo-variable `$this`
> is not available inside the method
> declared as static.

And :

> Calling non-static methods statically
> generates an `E_STRICT` level warning.

Answer (score 0):

Static call vs instance call. You'll want to grasp these basic OOP concepts. Have a read of the static keyword as well:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $this while a static call because $this is refers to object which is not created in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Test_Core::output()` because you are using wrong class name